# Create an array using php foreach

Tags: php, arrays

At the moment I have this code:

```
$divisions = explode(",", $mychecklist->dept);

foreach($divisions as $division) {
    $divs=get_record('induction_emails','id',$division);
    $useremail = get_record('user', 'email', $divs->email);
    echo $useremail->id;
}
```

This basically gets the division id from induction emails table, then checks the users table to match email to user. The final result I want is the user id's.

Once I have the user id's I want to put them into an array.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: imho, this is a bad design, if the `get_record` involve DB query, you won't like to iterate/repeatedly query database to get single record, reconstruct the function design to allow single query-->fetch all-->return the array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$divisions = explode(",", $mychecklist->dept);
$users = array();
foreach($divisions as $division) {
    $divs=get_record('induction_emails','id',$division);
    $useremail = get_record('user', 'email', $divs->email);
    echo $useremail->id;
    $users[] = $useremail->id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
$divisions = explode(",", $mychecklist->dept);
$ids = array();
foreach($divisions as $division) {
    $divs=get_record('induction_emails','id',$division);
    $useremail = get_record('user', 'email', $divs->email);
    $ids[] = $useremail->id;
}
print_r($ids);
```

Comment: thanks,  i had tried $ids[] = $useremail->id; but did not do $ids = array(); This works great, cheers

Answer (score 0):

Here is some pseudocode for using the `foreach` statement:

```
$users=array();

foreach(..) {
    ...
    $users[]=$useremail->id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are explained [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), together with some examples. In short:

```
$user_ids = array();
foreach(...){
    ...
    $user_ids[] = $useremail->id;
}
```